# EventListener function does not execute itself and the console does not return an error at all

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am a newbie, who has been trying to learn coding for a while. This is a primitive code for a crypto dex that I am building by following a tutorial. compared my code to the original, no differences at all. I am sure I have a typo somewhere, but I really can't see it.  The problem is that, when I click a button, it does not execute the function (event handler ):

```
const $tokenBalanceTbody=document.querySelector(".js-token-balances");
const $selectedToken=document.querySelector(".js-from-token");
const $amountInput=document.querySelector(".js-from-amount");



async function initSwapForm (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $selectedToken.innerText = event.target.dataset.symbol;
    $selectedToken.dataset.address=event.target.dataset.address;
    $selectedToken.dataset.decimals=event.target.dataset.decimals;
    $selectedToken.dataset.max=event.target.dataset.max;
    $amountInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
    $amountInput.value="";
    document.querySelector(".js-submit").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.querySelector(".js-cancel").removeAttribute("disabled");
    document.querySelector(".js-quote-container").innerHTML= "";

}

 // utilities 

async function getBalances () {
    const balances = await Moralis.Web3API.account.getTokenBalances();
    console.log(balances);
    $tokenBalanceTbody.innerHTML=balances.map((token,index)=>`
        <tr>
            <td>${index +1}</td>
            <td>${token.symbol}</td>
            <td>${tokenValue(token.balance, token.decimals)}</td>
            <td>
            <button
                    class="js-swap btn btn-info"
                    data-address="${token.token_address}"
                    data-symbol="${token.symbol}"
                    data-decimals="${token.decimals}"
                    data-max="${tokenValue(token.balance, token.decimals)}"
            >
            Swap
            </button>
            </td>
            
        </tr>
    `).join("");
}


for (let $btn of $tokenBalanceTbody.querySelectorAll(".js-swap")){
    $btn.addEventListener("click", initSwapForm)
}
```

I'm posting the HTML code as well:

```
   <table class="table table-dark table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Symbol</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="js-token-balances">
        </tbody>    
     </table>


    <form action="#" method="POST" class="exchange-form">
        <div class="row">
        <label>
                <span class="js-from-token"></span>
                Amount:
                <input type="text" name="from-amount" class="js-from-amount" disabled  />
        </label>
        <div class="js-amount-error error"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>
            Swap to:
            <select name="to-token"></select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <button type="submit" class="js-submit btn btn-info"  disabled >Get Quote</button> 
         <button class="js-cancel btn btn-info" disabled >Cancel</button>  

    </div>
    <div class="js-quote-container"></div>
    </form>
```

I can see that I have selected the class in the for loop in the right way. The function is supposed to remove the 'disabled' attributes of other buttons, but it does not happe. Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your code as HTML/CSS/JS snippet, it would let us see the problem in action easily. The best advice I can give you is to learn how to use the developer tools in your web browser and its debugger, you can check if the eventListener is correctly set for example.

Comment: looking again `$tokenBalanceTbody` will be empty until `getBalances` is executed - which never happens - even if it did, the `for (let $btn of $tokenBalanceTbody.querySelectorAll(".js-swap")){` has already run and done nothing - so you have many issues

Comment: Guys, thank you so much for your efforts and suggestions! I've just realised that the for loop was indeed out of the getBalances () fn which was the problem. Took me a total of 8 hours to find it. Works like a charm now! I sincerely appreciate your help!